# How does Flink (in streaming mode) assign task-to-CPU priority?

Tags: apache-flink

If I have the following code (and Flink is set to STREAMING mode, not batch, even though it's a bounded collection) and let's say I'm running on 10 nodes of 32 cores each:

```
DataStreamSource<...> ds = env.fromCollection(...); //large collection, eg 1e6 elements

ds
 .map() //expensive computation
 .flatMap()//generates 10,000x more elements for every 1 incoming element
 .rebalance()
 .map() //expensive computation
 ....//other transformations (ie can be a sink, keyby, flatmap, map etc)
```

What will Flink do with respect to task-to-CPU assignment priority when the SECOND map operation wants to process 10,000 elements that was generated from the 1st original element? Will it devote the 320 CPU cores (from 10 nodes) to processing the 1st original element's 10,000 generated elements? If so, will it "boot off" already running tasks? Or, will it wait for already running tasks to complete, and then give priority to the 10,000 elements resulting from the output of the `flatmap-rebalance` operations? Or, would the 10,000 elements be forced to run on a single core, since the remaining 319 cores are already being consumed by the output of the `ds` operation (ie the input of the 1st map). Or, is there some random competition for who gets access to the CPU cores?

What I would ideally like to have happen is that a) Flink does NOT boot off running tasks (it lets them complete), but when deciding which tasks gets priority to run on a core, it choses the path that would lead to the lowest latency, ie it would process all 10,000 elements which result from the output of the `flampat-rebalance` operation on all 320 cores.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

When Flink is running in streaming mode, then resources are allocated so that all tasks may run concurrently. Some tasks might finish, if they have bounded inputs, but there's also no attempt made to reallocate resources while a job is running.

All of the tasks running in the same slot are competing with each other for the resources available there. [Fine-grained resource management](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/finegrained_resource/) can be used to assign resources to slots. All of the slots in the same task manager are running in one JVM, and by default all of the tasks in those slots are competing in a free-for-all for all of the available resources.

Comment: When you say "free-for-all", is it truly random? Or, is there some logic to prioritize the task-to-CPU assignment (eg to reduce latency)? In particular, would it be fair to say that it follows a "first-come, first served" basis? If so, then I can "mimick" what I wish (possibly) by "trickle feeding" my input to Flink, so that the data gets processed in a certain order and has a higher likelihood of following the pattern that I want that I outlined in the original post.

Comment: Each Flink task has one primary (Java) thread. Tasks/threads without any actual work to do won't be consuming any CPU, and the other threads will run however the kernel and JVM decide to run them. You do need to be careful, however: if you block that primary thread checkpointing can not progress, and you might cause other problems as well. It's safer to apply rate limiting in deserializers (which run in their own threads).

Comment: Good to know. Minor clarification: I wasn't intending to do any rate-limiting within a Flink transformation; instead, I was going to do my "hack" by creating a tcp port and streaming data to that port slowly and in a defined way (and have flink read from that port). So, flink is more likely to process data in a way that I think would be efficient, ie "go deep in a pipeline tree and try to complete processing one input element" before "going wide". If you have any additional suggestions, I'm all ears.